# Does Buddhism have a creation myth?

Tags: metaphysics, buddhism, eastern-philosophy

How does Buddhism explain the world? Was it created or eternally existant? Do they have creation myths?

I'm asking this question, because what little & superficial knowledge I hve about Buddhism seems to be about the self, and not the world. At least as conventially understood.

Comment: I have a feeling Buddha was(is) solipsist.

Comment: Some traditions make a point of denying a creator god. The Mahayana cosmology posits multiple universes, each of which has existed forever.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the [Fourteen Unanswered Questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_unanswered_questions).

There is a [Buddhist Creation Myth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agga%C3%B1%C3%B1a_Sutta) told in the Aggañña Sutta, but it is clearly a satire and is not taken seriously.

Comment: What is satirical in it?

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no “Creation Myth” nor “God” in Buddhism.  See http://www.USABuddhism.com for info on Nichiren ShoShu True Buddhism.  Buddhism is a Practice we use to attain the Life Condition of Buddhahood or Enlightenment.

Comment: Buddhism per se may not have a creation myth; however the [aganna sutra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggañña_Sutta) in the Pali canon appears to detail one. I note that Michael Dorfmans answer refers to this, but whilst he says it clearly meant to be satirical, the wiki article does not refer to any satirical intent.